# jQuery datepicker Difference between "dateFormat" & "altFormat"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

According to this documentation, http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altFormat

I can set a different date format for the user to see, and a different format to actually send to the server.

However, both seem to show the same format.

Here is my code:

```
        $("#joindate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: $.datepicker.TIMESTAMP,
            altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
```

And, I would want the user to see yy-mm-dd format, and send the timestamp to the server using my post request. I have switched the values of altFormat and dateFormat, but either I get yy-mm-dd in both (textbox and $_POST) or the timestamp in both.

Is there a workaround to this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you must read this

> The dateFormat to be used for the
>   **altField** option. This allows one date
>   format to be shown to the user for
>   selection purposes, while a different
>   format is actually sent behind the
>   scenes. For a full list of the
>   possible formats see the formatDate
>   function

Reference:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField

Comment: Yes I know. Thats the same link that i posted in my question.

Comment: so where is problem Hrishikesh?? **altField :** The jQuery selector for another field that is to be updated with the selected date from the datepicker.

Comment: Just if someone else like me bumps into this thread: the OP is linking to **altFormat**; the answerer is linking to **altField**